# Pandas error_bad_lines will not work for 2 line

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading multiple csv files into a Dataframe and dropping lines with error using error_bad_lines, this has been working well until I got a file that has a line with errors on the 2nd line in a csv.
If I change the csv file to move the bad line to row 1 or any other row other then row 2 the code works, but leaving the bad line on row 2 it doesn't. What am I doing wrong ?

Sorry I was unable to figure out how to enter the output in a proper format, added it as pictures and added text at the bottom

Code:

```
label1="DATE"
label2="TIME"
label3="In1 "
label4="In2 "
header_label = [label1, label2, label3, label4]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='  | |,', names=header_label, engine='python', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False) for f in glob.glob("input/*.csv")],
               ignore_index=False)
```

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpnb1.png)

[Output File with Bad Row at #2 in Input CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDodT.png)
[Output File with Bad Row moved to any other spot other then ROW 2 of input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12tQN.png)

Input File:

```
2019/11/13 08:32  10.4,20.4
2019/11/13 13:58  752019/11/13 13:58  .4,123.9
2019/11/13 09:11  10.2,18.5
2019/11/13 09:22  9.5,14.8
2019/11/13 09:23  9.5,14.5
2019/11/13 09:24  9.3,14.6
2019/11/13 09:25  9.5,14.2
2019/11/13 09:26  9.0,13.4
2019/11/13 09:27  9.7,14.9
```

Output with file as is:

```
                          DATE  ...                  In1
2019/11/13 08:32          10.4  ...                  NaN
           13:58  752019/11/13  ...                123.9
           09:09  752019/11/13  ...                123.9
           09:11          10.2  ...                  NaN
           09:22           9.5  ...                  NaN
...                        ...  ...                  ...
```

Input File with row 2 moved to row 1:

```
2019/11/13 13:58  752019/11/13 13:58  .4,123.9
2019/11/13 08:32  10.4,20.4
2019/11/13 09:11  10.2,18.5
2019/11/13 09:22  9.5,14.8
2019/11/13 09:23  9.5,14.5
2019/11/13 09:24  9.3,14.6
2019/11/13 09:25  9.5,14.2
2019/11/13 09:26  9.0,13.4
2019/11/13 09:27  9.7,14.9
```

Output with Input Row 2 moved to Row 1 ( this is the output I want)

```
           DATE   TIME                   In1                  In2 
0    2019/11/13  08:32                  10.4                  20.4
1    2019/11/13  09:11                  10.2                  18.5
2    2019/11/13  09:22                   9.5                  14.8
3    2019/11/13  09:23                   9.5                  14.5
4    2019/11/13  09:24                   9.3                  14.6
..          ...    ...                   ...                   ...
```

Normally I would not be able to change the input file, just read them.
Why does the code work if I move the bad line to a different row other then row 2 ??
any help would be appreciated... Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your files, so I made an example here.
Anyway, you can use shape before concat and then concat the df to all.
If it is one line, you can read a line and not PD.readcsv and Concat check each line separately.

this is the example:

```
label1="DATE"
label2="TIME"
label3="In1 "
label4="In2 "
header_label = [label1, label2, label3, label4]

lists_csvis = [
pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13','08:32',10.4,20.4]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '13:58' , '752019/11/13' ,'13:58' , '.4','123.9']])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:11' , '10.2','18.5']])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:22' , '9.5',14.8]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:23' , '9.5',14.5]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:24' , '9.3',14.6]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:25' , '9.5',14.2]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:26' , '9.0',13.4]])
,pd.DataFrame([['2019/11/13', '09:27' , '9.7',14.9]])]


df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in lists_csvis:
    if f.shape[1] == len(header_label):
        df = pd.concat([df,f])
df.columns = header_label
df
```

[image: output:]

this is a code for your data:
*Edit: I understand that you have some files that make you trouble, so I added "try" and "except" so it will work fast and will print out the fils that have a problem. You can run line by line in the bad files that printed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("input/*.csv"):
    try:
        d = pd.read_csv(f, sep='  | |,', engine='python', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)
        if d.shape[1] == len(header_label):
            df = pd.concat([df,d])
    except:
        print("*** error file ***", f)
df.columns = header_label
df
```

here is how to read line by line:

```
from io import StringIO
path = "input/*.csv"
file_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            d = pd.read_csv(StringIO(line),sep='  | |,', header = None)
            if d.shape[1] == len(header_label):
                file_df = pd.concat([file_df,d])
                
file_df.columns = header_label
file_df
```

[image]

try this combination between read_csv and line by line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("input/*.csv"):
    try:
        d = pd.read_csv(f, sep='  | |,', header = None)
        if d.shape[1] == len(header_label):
            df = pd.concat([df,d])
    except:
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                d = pd.read_csv(StringIO(line),sep='  | |,', header = None)
                if d.shape[1] == len(header_label):
                    df = pd.concat([df,d])
file_df.columns = header_label
file_df
```

Comment: if you want I can add an example of how to read line by line.

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try. 
If you can a line by line read example would be helpful. 

One question though, why does the error_bad_lines not work if the line is in ROW2, if I move that bad row anywhere else the script works as intended. Is it something that I am doing wrong or a limitation ?

Comment: I assume the "error_bad_lines " is because of their shapes, in the "good lines" have 4 columns while the "bad_lines" have 6.

Comment: Hi, I had a few questions, if you had the time.
When I try to run the code with the glob.glob ( under heading: this is a code for your data) it gives me an error: expected 0 , new values have 4. Im still trying to understand why it is doing that. Secondly: the code for reading line by line works perfectly, however when reading all the CSV files (about 500) it takes a good 45-50 mins for it to process them, while with my original code with the offending line removed it would at most take 30-40 seconds. is there a way of speeding the process up or another method I should be using ?

Comment: I understand that you have some files that make you trouble so I added "try" and "except" so it will work fast and will print out the fils that have a problem. you can run line by line in the bad files that printed.

Comment: By the way, I am happy that one of the codes working :)

Comment: Thank you. I have the program working when reading line by line, but it is too slow currently to be used. 
I am trying to get the one with pandas error_bad_line to work, but for some reason it does not like a bad line on row 2 of the file, bad line can be on any other line and it works perfectly but as soon as a file is read with bad data on line 2 of a CSV it crashes

Comment: hi, this might help  you https://i.imgur.com/AhnaCtb.png

Comment: Thank you Ran, You have been of great help. I will give this a try. I was wondering if you would happen to know if there is a way to do the following:
Read first few lines of the CSV, check for bad Iines, delete bad lines and then continue reading the rest of the file using pd.concat /glob function.
kinda like this:
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='  | |,', names=header_label, engine='python', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False) for f in glob.glob read first few li=nes to check for bad lines, delete and then continue reading  ("input/*.csv")],
               ignore_index=False)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like lost the separator on "752019/11/13".
I think it should be "75 **<END_OF_LINE>** 2019/11/13", so add new line after 75 (with separator if required), save the file, and read it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm super new to programming and following tutorials, what I want accomplished is for the script to ignore the bad line. My question is how come if I move the bad line to any other ROW other then ROW 2, the code works but if it is at ROW 2 the output is skewed.
Thank you